# How to increase memory limitations in Octave

Tags: out-of-memory, octave

> error: out of memory or dimension too large for Octave's index type

According to the official [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.0/How-can-I-handle-memory-limitations_003f.html), I need to add a line like `-Xmx2048m` to file `java.opts`.

> "The directory where the Java options file is located is specified by
>   the environment variable OCTAVE_JAVA_DIR."

I don't have an environment variable with that name.

> If unset the directory where javaclasspath.m resides is used instead
>   (typically OCTAVE_HOME/share/octave/OCTAVE_VERSION/m/java/). You can
>   find this directory by executing `which javaclasspath`

That command doesn't work either (returns "which: no javaclasspath in ...")

I found what looks like the correct directory, but it doesn't have a file called `java.opts`. I created the file and added that line to it, but I'm still running into the same memory limitation error. I confirmed that the issue is not related to "dimension too large" and I restarted Octave several times.

How can I increase the memory limit in Octave?

Comment: That documentation is only for increasing the Java heap size which only affects creating Java objects. The memory limit that you're encountering is independent of Java and is a limitation of your system's memory. Do you have more information on your current system and the variable you're trying to create.

Comment: I have several GB of free memory, but I'm running out after Octave reserves ~0.8GB. I'm using Windows 10 and the variables are matrices which aren't too big (I can create several of them, but not too many before running out of memory, so it's not a dimension issue).

Comment: You are focusing on the wrong part of the error message. The error is "*out of memory **or** dimension too large for Octave's index type*". If you have several GB of free memory, then it can't be "*out of memory*" and therefore must be "*dimension too large for Octave's index type*". I guess you have a 32 bit build of Octave, which means Octave is using an int32 to indexing arrays, which means you can't have an array with more than 2147483647 elements. You need a 64 bit build of Octave and all of its Fortran dependencies.

Comment: It's not that. If I, for example, clear earlier matrices, I can build the new matrix. As in, if I free up memory from Octave, I can use more memory.

Comment: @AtteJuvonen: You may try the inofficial 64bit binaries fom Tatsuro MATSUOKA: http://www.tatsuromatsuoka.com/octave/Eng/Win/ Try one which supports "large arrays" (have "LA" in the name)

Comment: @AtteJuvonen: And I absolutely support carandraugs previous appraisal.