# octave: out of memory or dimension too large for Octave's index type

Tags: matlab, octave

i'm new to octave and i'm using version 4.2.1., 32bit. I'm getting this error when trying to operate with matrixs bigger than cca. 5000x5000. With smaller matrixs it works just fine. Is there a way to increase this allowed index type?

my code:

```
function [dt,F,u0,n1u]=solve_diff_sec_ord()
%n odd!!!!
n = input('Input number: '); #slice the interval[-1,1] to n+1 pieces
A = [];
for i=1:1:n 
  a = zeros(1,n+2);
  a(1,i)=1;
  a(1,i+1)=-2;
  a(1,i+2)=1;
  A = [A;a];  
end
B = A(:,[2:n+1]);
dt=det(B);
F=norm(B,'fro');
b=zeros(1,n);
h=2/(n+1);
for i=1:1:n
  if i <= (n+1)/2
    b(1,i)= (-1+i*h^2)+1;
  else
    b(1,i)= -(-1+i*h^2)+1;
  end
end
b=transpose(b);
x=linsolve(B,b,struct()); #basically solving D.E.
u0=x((n+1)/2,1);    
n1u=norm(x,1);
```

--> error: out of memory or dimension too large for Octave's index type

Comment: In my experience, this error tends to come up more when you've done something stupid leading to division by 'almost' 0, or something along those lines, leading to 'near' infinities etc, especially if you use these numbers to then create arrays of a particular size, leading to a request to octave to create an array of near-infinite size etc, which, obviously it cannot do because it exceeds the allowed size for a dimension. I seriously doubt it's an "available memory" issue (a 5000x5000 matrix of doubles takes about 200 Mb). Try debugging, I will bet that the error occurs way into the for loop.

Comment: Also see carandraug's comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494071/how-to-increase-memory-limitations-in-octave

Comment: Thank you for your opinion! Although I managed to overcome this problem using Thomas's algoritem for tridiagonal matrixs, I still want to come to the bottom of this issue.